# how to remove redundant whitespaces without using functions

Tags: python, whitespace

I need to remove redundant whitespaces from string without using any function like split(), strip() and so on. I have string like

```
" apples   bananas orange  "
```

and I need

```
"apples bananas orange".
```

So far I am here:

```
string = " apples   bananas orange  "
result = ""
output = ""
i = 0
while i < len(string):
    result = ""
    while string[i] != " ":
        result += string[i]
        i += 1
    while string[i] == " ":
        i += 1
        if i >= len(string):
            break
    output += result + " "

print(output)
```

But now I can not get rid of whitespaces on both sides.

I was also trying to get rid of whitespaces using just one cycle, but I am not able to add one whitespace between words.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "without using any function"?

Comment: I assume you mean without `split()` and `strip()` or `join()`? Because `len()` is a function.... `+` implicitly calls `__add__` function... `[i]` is also a `__getitem__` function

Comment: I have edited your question to mark up your desired output as code, which it wasn't before. Please check it carefully, as obviously whitespace is critical here.

Comment: In any case, the obvious way to solve the problem for practical purposes is `" ".join(string.split())`, so if you are going to get answers then I suspect you will need to convince people that there is an actual use case for avoiding functions (whatever you mean by that), other than as a programming exercise.

Comment: Yes, this is a homework, but I am quite desperate. Code has to be without any build-in function in python like split(), strip() and so on..

Answer (score 3):

Without any function, even `len`:

```
txt = " apples   bananas orange  "
out = ''
p = ' '  # the previous character

for c in txt:  # the current character
    if c == ' ' and p == ' ':  # continue if two consecutive white space
        continue
    p = c  # remember the current character for the next iteration
    out += c  # add the current character to the result

# remove the last character if remain a trailing white space
out = out if out and out[-1] != ' ' else out[:-1]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
'apples bananas orange'
```

Comment: If `txt` is empty string, this raises an `IndexError`. (Easily enough fixed: just put the final statement inside `if out:`.)

Comment: @alani. Thanks! I fixed my answer. Can you check it please if you see another case? :)

Comment: I can't think of another, although the last line might be clearer just as `if out and out[-1] == ' ': out = out[:-1]`

Comment: @alani. I prefer this "mathematical" notation. `"normal result" if "everything is normal" else "exception result"`

Comment: @Zhor. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to not use any sort of function.

Here is some code which *doesn't use a function*

```
s = " apples   bananas orange  "

# Remove start and end spaces
if s[0] == " ":
    s = s[1:]
if s[-1] == " ":
    s = s[:-1]
    
new_s = []
for i, c in enumerate(s[:-1]):
    if not (c == ' ' and s[i+1] == ' '):
        new_s.append(c)
print(''.join(new_s))
```

Technically `''join()` is a string-class function but if they tell you not to use that in python then they are wrong. This is python, not C.

Comment: `enumerate` is a function, `join` and `append` are methods. (and `print` is a function, lol)

Comment: @Corralien I assume they mean any string-class function, like `split`. In their example, he used `len` which is a function. Behdind the scenes of your answer it will be using the string's `__iter__` function to loop over the characters.

Comment: The OP said *without any built-in function*.

Comment: @Corralien OP's teacher should be teaching them C if they wanted to use *no* functions

Comment: This is an algorithmic problem not a python code... Python is good for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work in O(n):

```
s = " apples   bananas orange  "
s = s + ' '
i, j = 0, 0
out_str = ''
while j < len(s):
    if s[i] == ' ':
        i += 1
        j += 1
    elif s[j] != ' ':
        j += 1
    else:
        out_str += s[i:j] + ' '
        j = j + 1
        i = j
out_str = out_str[:-1]
out_str
```

Answer (score 0):

using stacks

```
def func(string):
    stack = []
    for i,v in enumerate(string):
        if (not stack and v==' ') or (stack and stack[-1]==' ' and v==' '):
            pass
        else:
            stack.append(v)
    if stack[-1]==' ':
        stack = stack[:-1]
    return ''.join(stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string = " apples   bananas orange  "
is_space = [s == ' ' for s in string]  # Boolean list of whether character is a space
current_word = ""                                                                                                                                    
result = ""                                                                                                                                  
# Iterate over each character and conduct appropriate action
for i in range(len(is_space)):
    # Start a new word
    if (
        (i == 0) or
        ((not is_space[i]) and (is_space[i - 1]))
    ): 
        current_word = string[i]
    # Add to the existing word
    elif (not is_space[i]) and (not is_space[i - 1]): 
        current_word += string[i]
    # Complete the word
    elif (is_space[i]) and (not is_space[i - 1]): 
        result += current_word + " "
# Remove trailing space
result = result[:-1]
# Display result
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = " apples   bananas orange  "
res = prev = ""
#hold back leading blanks and consecutive blanks withing string
for c in s:
    if c in (" ") and prev in (" ",""):
        pass
    else:
        res += c
    prev =c 
#strip off trailing blanks
while res[-1] == " ":
    res = res[:-1]
print(f":{res}:")
```

#### output:

```
:apples bananas orange:
```